# How to call a function if radiobutton is checked

Tags: javascript, html, events, radio-button

I have following HTML for radio button element. I want to call function showChildQuestions on `onchange` and `checked`. It works fine in onchange case but doesn't work in checked case. what am I doing wrong?

```
<input checked="checked showChildQuestions()" id="fname" name="fname" onchange="showChildQuestions(this);" type="radio">
```

Comment: It doesn't work that way; checked is a boolean attribute (either the RadioButton is checked, or it isn't). If you want to run code after the button is checked, call a helper function in `onchange` instead and check `checked` in there, then run the actual function.

Comment: checked is an attribute that defines the state of the input control, onchange is a listener that listenes for a change in the control's state and will fire once the "check" "uncheck" event is fired

Comment: If you want to trigger your function on `onchange` then if you checked or unchecked it your function will be triggered.  Why would you want to call again your function if `checked` ? You'll call twice your function if you check your checkbox

Answer (score 1):

checked is not callback like onChange is, you should use JQuery something like this

```
 $("#fname").click( function(){
   if( $(this).is(':checked') ) {
     showChildQuestions();
   }
 });
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
function showChildQuestions(a) {
  if (a.checked == true) {
    console.log("checked");
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="fname" name="fname" onchange="showChildQuestions(this);" type="radio">
```

Comment: Will this work in case where radiobutton is manually checked via HTML code like `checked =  "checked"` the first time document loads?

Comment: It's triggered `onchange`, that's an event listener that is triggered only when you click on it. What you want to do ?

Comment: I want to call `showChildQuestions()` when radiobutton has attribute `checked = "checked"` without clicking the radiobutton

Comment: How do you change the attribute ? JQuery/Js ? Why don't you execute `showChildQuestions()` at the same time ? Because from my example, `showChildQuestions()` is executed `onchange` and it checks if there is `checked = "checked"`

Comment: but from your example it wont call `showChildQuestions()` on document load. It will only be triggered when user clicks on it

Comment: That's what you asked `I want to call function showChildQuestions on onchange and checked`